# Playing a random audio file from a folder when a button is pressed with pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, raspberry-pi3

I want my raspberry to play a random audio file from a folder, everytime I press a button I connected with a GPIO. I already wrote a slightly different version of this program, but unfortunately it always plays the same file, everytime I press the button, so I have to restart the program to get another sound.

```
sndA = pygame.mixer.Sound(random.choice(attack))
SoundA = pygame.mixer.Channel(1)
while True: 
       try: 
        if (GPIO.input(4) == True):
          SoundA.play(sndA)
```

Here's the complete program:

```
import pygame.mixer
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from sys import exit
import random
import time
import glob
import pygame.event

attack = glob.glob("attack/*.wav") #folder with attack quotes
move = glob.glob("movement/*.wav") #folder with move/idle quotes
taunt = glob.glob("taunt/*.wav") #folder with taunt quotes
joke = glob.glob("joke/*.wav") #folder with the jokes
laugh = glob.glob("laugh/*.wav") #folder with the laughing tracks
pick = glob.glob("pick/*.wav") #folder with pick/ban quotes
misc = glob.glob("misc/*.wav")

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.IN)
pygame.mixer.init(48000, -16, 1, 1024)
sndA = pygame.mixer.Sound(random.choice(attack))
sndB = pygame.mixer.Sound(random.choice(move))
sndC = pygame.mixer.Sound(random.choice(taunt))
sndD = pygame.mixer.Sound(random.choice(joke))
sndE = pygame.mixer.Sound(random.choice(laugh))
sndF = pygame.mixer.Sound(random.choice(pick))
sndG = pygame.mixer.Sound(random.choice(misc))
SoundA = pygame.mixer.Channel(1)
SoundB = pygame.mixer.Channel(2)
SoundC = pygame.mixer.Channel(3)
SoundD = pygame.mixer.Channel(4)
SoundE = pygame.mixer.Channel(5)
SoundF = pygame.mixer.Channel(6)
SoundG = pygame.mixer.Channel(7)

print ("Soundboard aktiv.");

while True:

    try:
        if (GPIO.input(4) == True):
            SoundA.play(sndA)

        if (GPIO.input(17) == True):
            SoundB.play(sndB)

        if (GPIO.input(18) == True):
            SoundC.play(sndC)

        if (GPIO.input(21) == True):
            SoundD.play(sndD)

        if (GPIO.input(23) == True):
            SoundE.play(sndE)

        if (GPIO.input(24) == True):
            SoundF.play(sndF)

        if (GPIO.input(25) == True):
            SoundG.play(sndG);


    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit()
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question to include the code you have already written - that will assist the community in helping you. Thanks.

Comment: I can't include the code directly but I can put it on pastebin
https://pastebin.com/MZUUudKN

Comment: If you can't include the code because there is too much, cut it down to a 'minimal, verifiable and complete example' that demonstrates the problem. This community expects code physically present in the question, because links are liable to disappear, breaking the StackOverflow knowledge base. You are very unlikely to get an answer unless you paste something.

Answer (score 1):

Load all sounds and append them to a list.

```
attack_sounds = []
for sound_file in glob.glob("attack/*.wav"):
    attack_sounds.append(pygame.mixer.Sound(sound_file))
```

Then call `random.choice` with this list as the argument to pick a random sound out of the list and play it.

```
if GPIO.input(4):
    random_sound = random.choice(attack_sounds)
    random_sound.play()
```

Comment: Likely the OP is having issues with the `glob` objects, which are generators.

Comment: @PMende [glob.glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) returns a list of path names.

Comment: So it does! I'm used to globs on `pathlib.Path` objects. My bad.

Comment: If I try to use this, it just gives me an error:
"Unable to open file" at "the attack_sounds.append" part

Comment: Did it work in your original example? I've tested the code on my PC and it works correctly. Are all your .wav files in the `attack` directory faultless? Can you play them with other software? Check out what happens if you load all sounds separately, e.g.: `sound1 = pygame.mixer.Sound("attack/first_sound.wav")`, 
`sound2 = pygame.mixer.Sound("attack/second_sound.wav")`, etc..

Comment: The files are playable, and separated it works aswell. The separated way is my basic modell in a nutshell.

Comment: Check out if a specific file doesn't work in the for loop: `print(sound_file)` before you create the instance with `pygame.mixer.Sound`.

Comment: It seems like it's file number 5, but I can play the files on it's own. (Or at least it gives me "attack5.wav" as the file in cannot open.)

Comment: nvm, I deleted the attack5 file and now it says it's attack1.wav

Comment: Could you upload one of the problematic files?

Comment: Works correctly for me. What could be causing this problem? Please print `glob.glob("attack/*.wav")` and also print the paths (`sound_file`) in the for loop and post the results here.

Comment: turns out I was a bit stupid and put it in the wrong place. So thanks for that, but now it's not random, it just plays alls files at once

Comment: I'd have to see your updated code in order to help you.

Comment: So while `GPIO.input(17)`, etc. are True it will play random sounds all the time for each iteration of the while loop. You could check if the [mixer is busy](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.get_busy) with `if not pygame.mixer.get_busy(): random_sound.play()` to play only one sound at a time (you can also do that for each of the channels). Or maybe use interrupts: https://raspi.tv/2013/how-to-use-interrupts-with-python-on-the-raspberry-pi-and-rpi-gpio I'm not familiar with the RaspberryPi, so I'm not sure if that will help you.